# Connection Error while connecting Xamarin.Forms with MySQL database

Tags: mysql, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I am new to Xamarin.Forms mobile development and using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.10.2 and database MySQL 8.0 Version 8.0.19 installed on same system. I am trying to connect to a MySQL database locally using connection sting but getting an error **(MySqlConnector.MySqlException: 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.')**.  But when I am trying to connect to the database with the help of ***ADD CONNECTION*** service that is provided by Visual Studio it's getting connected.

I googled a lot but nothing is making my way.

**My code is as Below  (As I was facing connection problem in my original project I m just trying in one small project.)**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using MySqlConnector;

namespace ServerConnection
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Pro_Connect(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection Con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=databasename; uid=root; password= password;");
            Con.Open();
            if (Con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                Con.Open();
                await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Connected.", "Ok");
            }
            else
                await DisplayAlert("Alert","Connection Not found.","Ok");
        }
    }
}
```

I know that in MySQL Remote access is not allowed by default to the root user and it's not a good idea, but I used below command to confirm about authentication for the user

**GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;**

I tried to provide all the information that you can understand in a better way to reply me. If is there anything left for your knowledge to help me out then please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: first, connecting directly to a remote db from a mobile client is a horrible idea and you shouldn't do it.  Second, don't use "localhost", use the IP or FQDN of the server

Comment: Thanks Jason. Its working now. your advice is also marked regarding direct connection.